# CSS Grid: Center Content And Left Align Text

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I think there should be an easy solution here but I can't quite find it. I want to re-create something like the following image:

[image]

Notice how the item and quantity rows are centered below the details title, but the text contained within them is left-aligned. Here is my attempt:

```css
.grid-container {
  background: gray;
  display: inline-grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  padding: 10px;
}

.details {
  font-weight: bold;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.info {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="details">Details</div>
      <div class="info">Item</div>
      <div class="info">Beans</div>
      <div class="info">Quantity</div>
      <div class="info">41</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

but you can see that, although the content is centered correctly, the text is not left-justified. Is there a way to do this with CSS grid?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove `justify-items: center` (this justify each item's content to the center of that item) and set `justify-self: center` for `.details`.

Try it:

```css
.grid-container {
  background: gray;
  display: inline-grid;
  align-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  padding: 10px;
}

.details {
  font-weight: bold;
  grid-column: span 2;
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="details">Details</div>
  <div class="info">Item</div>
  <div class="info">Beans</div>
  <div class="info">Quantity</div>
  <div class="info">41</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah I see this makes a lot of sense, only targeting the one component you need centered, got it! Thank you